# Android Roll Out Menu

Tags: android, button, menu, rollout

I am having a hard time to find some example code, which would allow me to roll out a little menu where I would want to place 6 check boxes. Something which would allow to collapse using a single click.

I want to use this type of action rather than taking person to another screen dedicated to just couple of check boxes.

Example of what I am looking for would be similar to this:
https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/de.betaapps.andlytics/ss-480-0-6
, where rating option which you'll see in the screenshot is completely collapsible, by pressing a little arrow to the right side of it.

Any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [Expandable ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). You can see an [example of it here](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/02/expandable-lists-and-check-boxes.html).